# Stop the SoundEffect from looping

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I'am building a game in C#/XNA, it is an top-view racing game and I want to play a sound effect, when my car bumps into a wall.

The problem is that my sound keeps looping so, when I hit a wall, the song will instantly start playing, but I want it to play, and when it is finished playing, then it can be played again.

Here is the code that takes care of the collision:

`if (map[x][y] == 0)` 
`{`
               `car.speed = 0;`

```
crash.Play(); }
```

Please ask me if I'am not clear about something.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Crash is the SoundEffect

Answer (score 4):

Here is the complete answer to your questions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940203.aspx

```
SoundEffectInstance instance = soundEffect.CreateInstance();
instance.IsLooped = true;
```

However, by default, SoundEffect should not be looped...

Answer (score 2):

Call [SoundEffect.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.createinstance.aspx) to get a [SoundEffectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx).  Then set the [IsLooped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.islooped.aspx) property to false before you call [Play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.play.aspx):

```
crashSoundEffectInstance.IsLooped = false;
```

Comment: I want to try that, without using the soundeffectinstance class, I just want to know when the soundeffect has ended playing, so when it is finished, i can fire it again.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the `SoundEffectInstance` class. Here's an [example](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/playing-sound-effects) on how to use it properly.

You can check if the sound effect state to see if it's currently playing

**Edit:** I've added a more complete code, as I felt it was needed. It's roughly the same example as in the link I've provided. (Note: This code is untested)

```
//In your content load
SoundEffect crash;
crash = Content.Load<SoundEffect>("PathToYourSoundEffect");
SoundEffectInstance sei = crash.CreateInstance();

//In your update code
if(sei.State == SoundState.Stopped || sei.State == SoundState.Paused)
{
    sei.Play();
}
```

Comment: but if I enter crash.State == SoundState.stopped, it says that State doesn't exist, should I create an instance for that?

Comment: You have to create a `SoundEffectInstance` to wrap your crash sound. Then you will be able to check the sound's current state. See the example link I've provided, it's really clear and concise.